# Error 91 when saving "Selection" to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to do something that should be simple, save the current selected cell to a range variable. A single cell is selected.

```
Function SelectionInfo() As Range
    SelectionInfo = Selection
    Debug.Print "SelectionInfo " + SelectionInfo.Address
    SelectionInfo.Select
End Function
```

But I get an error on the very 1st line of the function "Run-time error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Replace with `Set SelectionInfo = Selection`

Comment: `SelectionInfo` must be initialized using `Set`

Comment: Pedantically - you might want to check the type of the selection (or wrap with error handling) since it would crash if e.g. a shape is the selected object when the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use a **sub** rather than a **function**

```
Sub SelectionInfo()
    Dim s As String
    s = TypeName(Selection)
    MsgBox s

    If s = "Range" Then MsgBox Selection.Address
    If s = "Shape" Then MsgBox Selection.Name
    If s = "ChartArea" Then MsgBox Selection.Name
End Sub
```